# Interpolated Environment Variable unset in cronjob using /bin/ip command

Tags: ubuntu, environment-variables, crontab

I have the following script in myuser's home directory

```
#!/bin/bash
# startup.sh
export HOST_IP=$(/bin/ip -4 addr show enp2s0 | /bin/grep -Po 'inet \K[\d.]+')
echo "Using HOST_IP=$HOST_IP"
```

and the following entry in my user's crontab (not the root crontab)

`@reboot /home/myuser/startup.sh > /home/myuser/restart.log 2>&1`

If I run the command myself I see the following output

```
> ./startup.sh
Using HOST_IP=192.168.1.15
```

But if I reboot the machine and then inspect `restart.log` I see

```
> cat ./restart.log
Using HOST_IP=
```

I'm using the full path's to the `ip` and `grep` commands, so I don't understand why I'm getting no value for the environment variable when it is run from the crontab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `@reboot` cron job runs *before the address is set.*

A more reliable approach would be to run the script from your network configurator's "post-up" hook mechanism, e.g. via `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d`.

Comment: I ended up making a systemd unit file for running my script and that worked perfectly. Thanks.